# How can I display a users profile to another user with the FOUserbundle in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.1

I would like to give the user a possibility to display other users, so that they can check out e.g. the level of other users.

Is there a way to give each user a specific route? As an example: **/username/profile** ?
Should I create a new view and a new controller for this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have a look at Sonata AdminBundle. You can use it to manage your data and it can be used with FOS UserBundle to manage users as well.

Comment: is there no possibility with the FOSUserbundle itself? Sonata seems to be a bit to far away concerning the use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it with the help of @Alex:

The user controller which handles the displaying of all list with all FOSUserBundle users + the displaying of each user individually:

```
/**
 * User controller.
 */
class UsersController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all CategoryShop entities.
     *
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('DbeUserBundle:User')->findAll();

        return $this->render('DbeUserBundle:Users:userlist.html.twig', array(
                'entities' => $entities,
        ));

    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a CategoryShop entity.
     *
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('DbeUserBundle:User')->find($id);



        return $this->render('DbeUserBundle:Users:userprofile.html.twig', array(
                'entity'      => $entity,
                   ));
    }
```

Here is the routes for the two actions:

```
 <route id="fos_user_profile_show_users" pattern="/users">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Users:index</default>
</route>
 <route id="fos_user_profile_show_user" pattern="/user/{id}">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Users:show</default>
</route>
```

I finnaly allowed even non-authenticated users to list all users. So there was no need for a setting in the firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Create a route and controller such as `/users` which lists all Users. Only give access to `/users` to a particular role.  Create a further route and controller such as `users/{id}` and have your controller extract the necessary information for that user that you wish to display. The trick here is that you restrict it to super admin users, for example

So your security.yml may look like this:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ...
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

access_control:
    ...
    - { path: ^/users, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Great. I have just done it on a recent project so if you have any problems I can hopefully help